# Find a Möbius transformation which maps the region $|z| > 1$, $\Im z > 0$ onto the first quadrant of the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

a) Find a Möbius transformation which maps the region $|z| > 1$, $\Im z > 0$ onto the first quadrant of the complex plane.

b) Find **all** Möbius transformations satisfying the above requirement.

I know how to find Möbius transformations in general, using the cross-ratio, but in this case I don't even know how to start. Any input is appreciated! I am studying for an exam in complex analysis.

Comment: You are just missing the intuition that M\"obius transformations map lines/circles to other lines/circles. As you know the transformations are determined by mappings of three points. So for instance, if you want to map an arc to a line, pick three points on the arc and map them to three points on a line via cross-ratios.

Comment: @Evan I am well aware that Möbius transformations map lines/circles to other lines/circles! In this case, we are mapping a more complicated area. How would you start?

Comment: But the region boundary is just  circles/lines.  You want to pay special attention to the points $-1,1$.  Mapping things to $\infty$ does wonders sometimes.  It's a general trick for sending circular arcs to straight lines.  PS sorry for the wrong assumption!

Comment: @Evan Can you be more specific? I do not know which points to select from the region. Edit: I can select $z_{1}=-1$ and $z_{2}=1$ and map them to arbitrary points on the boundary of the first quadrant, but I do not see how this helps.

Comment: Ok sure. Send $-1$ to $0$, $1$ to $\infty$, and pick another point on the arc, say $i$ and send it to $1$? The other part will be automatic, because analytic functions preserve angles in the mapping.

Comment: This dialogue is helpful, thank you. But how come that the resulting Möbius transformation will map our area and not the the unit circle onto the first quadrant?

Comment: It's a good question. For instance after you do the transformation, you could test a point in the region to make sure it does go to the  quadrant. I suppose another intuition is that an analytic function respects symmetries (related to reflection principle), and if you consider the four regions (your region, upper semicircle, lower semicircle, lower region), they must map to the four quadrants, and it's a matter of "no room for the map to go the other way". Hmm.. I'm sure someone could come up with a better explanation than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each generalized circle (circle or line) is mapped to another generalized circle, the image of $|z|=1$ is $\Re z = 0, \Im z \ge 0$ and the image of $\Im z = 0$ is $\Im z = 0, \Re z \ge 0$, or vice versa. In both cases either $-1 \mapsto 0$, $1 \mapsto \infty$ or $-1 \mapsto \infty$, $1 \mapsto 0$. So our mapping must be of the form
$$z \mapsto a\frac{z+1}{z-1}$$
or
$$z \mapsto a\frac{z-1}{z+1}.$$
The point $0$ is on the real line, but outside our region. So it is mapped either to negative real halfline or negative imaginary halfline. Therefore $a=\alpha$ or $a=i\alpha$, where $\alpha > 0$. We also know that $i$ is mapped to the boundary of the first quadrant. This means that we have an imaginary $a$ for the mapping of the first form and a real $a$ for the mapping of the second form. So the general form of Möbius transformations satisfying the requirement is

> $$z \mapsto i\alpha\frac{z+1}{z-1}, \quad \alpha >0, \qquad \text{ or } \qquad z \mapsto \alpha\frac{z-1}{z+1}, \quad \alpha >0.$$